# What is the correct way to add references inside a chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, overleaf

I am writing a document divided by chapters, with each chapter appearing in this format:
[image]

And, I want to add at the end the references in this format:
[image]

...and I want them to appear in this way:
[image]

The code I'm using is this:

```
% INITIAL PACKAGES:
%Biber using IEEE style for proper UTF-8 support
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references.bib}


%END OF THE DOCUMENT:
\begingroup
\chapter{References}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{footnotesize}
%Redefine References name
\defbibheading{multilevel}[References]
\SingleSpacing
\setlength{8pt}
\printbibliography[heading=multilevel]
\endgroup
```

However, when I try to add the references, on the line "\printbibliography[heading=multilevel]" I get a warning that says "empty bibliography on input line 318" and no references appear. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For a start, did you try `\addbibresource{references.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{references.bib}`? The former is the standard way to import (a) bibliography set(s) with `biblatex`

Comment: Thank you! Yes I did but I still have the same problem, the references don't appear.